# Java: What does ~ mean

Tags: java, syntax, operators, special-characters

In this Java source code I have this line:

```
if ((modifiers & ~KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0) ....
```

What does the tilde `~` mean?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The Tilde (`~`) performs a bitwise complement of a numerical value in Java.

See: [Bitwise complement (`~`): inverts ones and zeroes in a number](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Bitwisecomplementinvertsonesandzeroesinanumber.htm)

Answer (score 60):

It is the [Unary ~ Bitwise complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation#C_family_of_languages) operator *(quoting)* :

- only used with integer values
- inverts the bits ie a 0-bit becomes 1-bit and vice versa
- in all cases ~x equals (-x)-1

See also [this page on Bitwise operators on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT), which states :

> The bitwise NOT, or complement, is a
>   unary operation that performs logical
>   negation on each bit, forming the
>   ones' complement of the given binary
>   value. Digits which were 0 become 1,
>   and vice versa. 
> For example:

```
NOT 0111  (decimal 7)
  = 1000  (decimal 8)
```

> In many programming languages
>   *(including those in the C family)*, the bitwise NOT operator is "`~`"
>   (tilde).

Answer (score 23):

From Java's website http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

> The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it
> can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1"
> and every "1" a "0". For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying
> this operator to a value whose bit pattern is "00000000" would change
> its pattern to "11111111".

Now, as previously answered by Pascal MARTIN, at any given case the value equals to -(x)-1. E.g. ~2=-3, ~-6=5, etc.

Also, in java all **positive integers** are stored as their binary representations and **negative integers** are stored in 2's complement value of a positive integer.

Now, let's see how it works in bit level in case of ~2=-3:

Initially, 2 is stored in its binary representation:

```
0000 0000 0000 0010
```

Now ~2 will result in the value (inverse the bits):

```
1111 1111 1111 1101
```

How in the world I know it is -3?
Well, it is -3 because it is derived from 2's complement representation of 3.

As we know 2's(x)= 1's(x) + 1 (https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/binary-lesson-12-ones-complement-and-twos-complement/) 
**Our aim is it to find x**: 
1's(x)= 2's(x) - 1 (based on previous expression)

As our answer is in is in 2's complement,
1's(x)= `1111 1111 1111 1101 - 0000 0000 0000 0001` 
1's (x)= `1111 1111 1111 1100` (How to subtract -http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/pm/sub.html) 
Therefore x= 1's complement of value (as the answer we got represents 1's complement of x). 
x = `0000 0000 0000 0011` 
 So, we have found that x is 3 and hence our previous result of ~ operator `1111 1111 1111 1101`is -3 written as 2's complement of 3.

Answer (score 11):

As said before `~` is the unary bitwise NOT operator.
Your example tests whether `modifiers` contains bits other than those defined in `KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK`.

- `~KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK` -> all bits except those in KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK are set to 1.
- `(modifiers & ~KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK)` -> every 1-bit in `modifiers` that "does not belong" to `KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK`
- `if ((modifiers & ~KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0)` -> if there was at least one other bit set to 1 besides `KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK` do something...

Answer (score 4):

From the official docs http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html:

> The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1" and every "1" a "0". For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying this operator to a value whose bit pattern is "00000000" would change its pattern to "11111111".