# How to use tilde ~ in a Java String

Tags: java, arrays, math

I have to find the twos Complement of a decimal number. The input is in Byte and the result should be in String. I have already written a program that converts decimal to binary but i don't know how to convert binary String to ones Complement aka replacing 0 with 1 and 1 with 0.

This is what I have written so far:

```
String toTwoComp(byte n) {
    String s = "";
    byte num = n;
    String res = "";
    while (n > -128 && n < 127) {
        s = (num % 2) + s;
        num = (byte) (num / 2);
        if (num == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    res = "00000000".substring(s.length()) + s;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483504/java-what-does-mean

Comment: `break;}
    }` the code is not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Two's complement of any byte or int `x` is just `-x`.  So did you try this?

```java
   String b = toTwosComp((byte)3);
   System.out.println(b);


   static String toTwosComp(byte n) {
      int twosComp = -n;
      return Integer.toBinaryString(twosComp & 0xFF);
   }
```

Note that you can do this and just use your own method to convert to a binary string.

Comment: this is a homework and unfortunately i am not allowed to use 'Integer.toBinaryString((<Zahl> & 0xFF) + 256).substring(1)'

Comment: Then just use your own method to convert decimal to a binary string.  You said that already worked.

Comment: how do I convert a binary string to ones complement?